# Laravel: How to convert raw SQL to eloquent/fluent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I currently have this mysql query as DB::raw. But I feel that using eloquent and/or fluent is more efficient and better. Can you give me some help in converting this:

```
SELECT trackers.\*, traces.\*
FROM trackers, traces
WHERE trackers.user_id = 4 AND traces.id = (SELECT id FROM traces WHERE msisdn = 1234567890 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: more efficient? No. Eloquent does nothing else than the raw sql does. Except that it has to be parsed first too. So I'd rather say the raw sql is better.

Comment: Are you trying to convert an old db ? then try https://github.com/adamkearsley/laravel-convert-migrations otherwise there's no way other than rewriting each query in to eloquent

Comment: @YUNOWORK But keep in mind that if using raw sql statements you will have to escape user input etc. yourself and in case of using eloquent/fluent you don't have to worry about that. In point of efficiency you are right but I would go for a raw sql only if it is a bottleneck here.

Comment: @VeeBee The key word for such a query is *nested eloquent query* and this can be archived by a closure. See an example here: http://laravel.io/forum/03-05-2014-nested-query-in-from